# When does a pinacol undergo dehydration or rearrangement?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, elimination

[image]

What happens when the above pinacol is treated with -
(a) conc. sulphuric acid
(b) dil. sulphuric acid

I'm confused between pinacol rearrangement and dehydration (E1 or E2?), as both possibilities exist. I think the concentration of the reagent might have a role to play, but I'm not sure. Please help.

P.S. It'd be great if you could quote data and sources with your answer.

Comment: Epoxide formation under dilute conditions?

Comment: I wonder if treatment with conc. sulphuric acid would form some octamethyl-1,4-dioxan (in analogy to glycol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you treat pinacol with sulfuric acid, an E1 elimination will take place ( having a carbocation as intermediate ) and it forms pinacolone ( 3,3-dimethyl-2-butanone ). I am not aware of how concentrated the acid should be. Do you require a photo depicting the mechanism ?

Comment: Is it possible for both the OH groups to eliminate?

Comment: No. If that happened, you would technically end up with 2 positive charges next to each other and that is not favourable. When a proton “attacks” one of the hydroxyl group, it leaves as water and a positive charge is left on the carbon and that rearranges. In all the books, this is the mechanism that appears.

Comment: That wouldn't happen, elimination could happen one after the other.

Comment: How could they happen one after the other when, after the first one, a ketone is formed ? How can a ketone eliminate water like that ?